# Studied, having studied or has studied?

Tags: grammar, formality

This is a translation of my high school graduation certificate:

> This is to certify that XXX, male, ethnic group of Han, born in March 1988, native of A County, B City, C Province, **studied** in our school from September 2003 to June 2006, has completed all the courses stipulated...

Should I use *studied*, *having studied* or *has studied* in the first sentence?

Also, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You should also change *with qualified scores*. This phrase has some ambiguity. *qualified* can mean subject to qualification (i.e. with caveats). *with qualifying scores* would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using "having studied."

This is called the perfect participle (or more accurately a participial clause), and is appropriate in this case because it reflects a *completed* action. In this scenario, I presume they are receiving recognition and are eligible for graduation because they have completed all required studies. To capture both a) the finality of their studies and b) the extent of their studies, you should have a participial clause.

"Studied" is not correct. A student may have studied, but not necessarily *completed* their studies and thereby be eligible to graduate. (Note that "studied" may be correct if you intend to bestow eligibility on a student that studied sometime in the past, for an indeterminate amount of time and to unknown progress. From what I gather, that's not what you want.)

"Has studied" is not correct. Just plug it into the sentence. It sounds silly because it is wrong (though not vice versa). With some rewording and adding a who or whom, you could make this work. But it would still be messy and weird.

[Here](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participleperfect.html) is an okay primer on the perfect participle. I'll try to find a better one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I think of "has studied" as a parallel component to "has completed" (This is to certify that somebody has studied in our school and has completed all the courses)? Also, is there more polishing can be done to this translation?

Comment: "But it would still be messy and weird." - agreed, I do find "having studied" more natural, and your elaboration on perfect participle is very helpful.

Comment: I think the rest is perfectly acceptable @Aufheben. I would maybe say, "of ethnic group Han," but I think the way you have it is fine.

Comment: Also, as @virmaior mentioned, "with qualifying scores" would probably be more clear.

Comment: diplomas use a more formal language, and *having completed* is common.

Answer (score 1):

I think jboneca's answer above is perfect if this sentence has no subsequent verbs. When I first read it, however, I interpreted it as the first two parts of a three-part sequence: "studied...has completed..." [and done something else, e.g., graduated in the top ten of his class]. It comes down to what appears after the ellipsis.

If this sentence has only two parts, then you either have to write "having studied [at] our school from September 2003 to June 2006, has completed" or delete the comma and insert "and": "studied [at] our school from September 2003 to June 2006 and has completed..."

I think "studied" is acceptable when describing a duration of time ("from September 2003 to June 2006"), but if you want to use it instead of a perfect participle ("having studied"), you have to coordinate the two verbs with "and."